# How can I solve this Excel drop-down menu error: “You may not use reference operators…”

Tags: microsoft-excel

I am trying to make a drop down menu using data validation in Excel. I just want the choices to be A, C or D, but when I select them as the source for the menu it gives me this error.

> “You may not use reference operators (such as unions, intersections and ranges) or array constants for Data Validation criteria.”

From the internet, it seems I need to manually input 'A, C, D' into the source. However, as there are many words in the actual cells (as the source for the menu).

Are there methods for me to quickly do that?
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The values list should be written like this: `$A$1,$B$1,$C$1`.

The equal (`=`) at the beginning made Excel think this is a formula
rather than a list.

Answer (score 1):

Create auxiliary columns, copy and past the values to auxiliary columns:
[image]

Change the reference source to auxiliary columns:

[image]